# How can I train a model for specific information extraction

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I have a dataset of verdict sentences texts that looks like this
"The defendant has been found guilty of armed robbery and is hereby sentenced to 10 years in prison, and sentencing him to a fine of five dollars and fees. After considering the defendant's cooperation with the investigation and lack of prior convictions, the sentence is reduced to 5 years in prison starting from the day this ruling becomes final."

how can I train/tune a model/(which models are best) and preprocess the data to understand the text and give me only the reduced sentence "5 years in prison starting from the day this ruling becomes final." as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem to be framed as summary generation task.

To keep things simple and provide you with a starting point, here are some essential aspects to consider

- You can have 2 types of summarization: abstractive and extractive.
- Your case is the former, as you do want to have just a
  summary/inherent logic of the input text captured, not to extract only some
  specific words. If you wanted only the latter you could also frame your problem as a NER (named-entity recognition one), not only an extractive summarization one.
- You would need to generate training pairs such as `[full_text,summary]` in order to train your model.
- For such a dataset (abstractive summarization) you can try searching
  online, here is an example of such dataset :
  https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/billsum.
- Once you see how the dataset looks like, you can try to create a
  similar dataset on your own and then fine-tune an LLM to cater for
  your use-case. Here is a tutorial on HuggingFace on how to perform fine-tuning on abstractive summarization on the exact dataset specified above: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/summarization

Comment: The same steps/approach work in case I have an Arabic dataset, right? and what's the best mechanism  given that I have only 1900 sample

Comment: Same steps work for Arabic, you have to ensure you have a pretrained model that can handle Arabic language. I cannot say for certain how it would works, 1900 I assume it's a good starting point but you may need to add more data.